# Encode specific attribute in a nested map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to use the Terraform EKS module but have difficulty passing configuration values for my addons.

In my variable files, I have a map for all of my clusters and their configurations, it looks like this:

```
    clusters = {
      cluster1 = {
          cluster_addons = {
            first_addon = {
              addon_version = "1.2.3"
              configuration_value = {...} # to be encoded at runtime
            },
            second_addon = {
              addon_version = "1.5.2"
              configuration_value = {...} # to be encoded at runtime too
            }
          }
      }
      cluster2 = {
        ...
      }
    }
```

The output I want, is a map with addons for each cluster, including the JSON encoded configurations, for example:

```
    addons = {
      cluster1 = {
            first_addon = {
              addon_version = "1.2.3"
              configuration_value = {...} # This is now JSON encoded
            },
            second_addon = {
              addon_version = "1.5.2"
              configuration_value = {...} # This is now JSON encoded
            }
      }
      cluster2 = {
          ... # Another cluster configuration
      }
    }
```

I came up with the following code, that almost does what I want:

```
  eks_addons = merge(flatten([
    for cluster_name, cluster in var.eks_clusters : [
      for addon_name, addon in cluster.cluster_addons : {
        "${cluster_name}" = { # Here is the problem, I override the addons and only keeps the last one
          "${addon_name}" = {
            addon_version        = lookup(addon, "addon_version", "")
            configuration_values = jsonencode(lookup(addon, "configuration_values", {}))
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ])...)
```

The problem with this snippet is that I override the addons and only keep the last addon, instead of just appending the objects with the encoded configurations to the same map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close! The changes are mainly just swapping two of your lines, and then tidying up some of the overcomplication of making a list then flattening and merging. Here's a self-contained, fully working version that you should be able to tweak to fit your purpose:

```
locals {
  clusters = {
    cluster1 = {
      cluster_addons = {
        first_addon = {
          addon_version = "1.2.3"
          configuration_value = {
            v1 = 12
            v2 = "34"
          }
        },
        second_addon = {
          addon_version = "1.5.2"
          configuration_value = {
            v1 = "45"
            v3 = 19
          }
        }
      }
    }
    cluster2 = {
      cluster_addons = {
        third_addon = {
          addon_version       = "2.3.4"
          configuration_value = {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

locals {
  eks_addons = {
    for cluster_name, cluster in local.clusters :
    cluster_name => {
      for addon_name, addon in cluster.cluster_addons :
      addon_name => {
        addon_version        = lookup(addon, "addon_version", "")
        configuration_values = jsonencode(lookup(addon, "configuration_value", {}))
      }
    }
  }
}

output "out" {
  value = local.eks_addons
}
```

When I run this, I get

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + out = {
      + cluster1 = {
          + first_addon  = {
              + addon_version        = "1.2.3"
              + configuration_values = jsonencode(
                    {
                      + v1 = 12
                      + v2 = "34"
                    }
                )
            }
          + second_addon = {
              + addon_version        = "1.5.2"
              + configuration_values = jsonencode(
                    {
                      + v1 = "45"
                      + v3 = 19
                    }
                )
            }
        }
      + cluster2 = {
          + third_addon = {
              + addon_version        = "2.3.4"
              + configuration_values = jsonencode({})
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, and it is also a lot cleaner than my flattening and merging :)